# Mutate pandas dataframe cell values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to mutate column `c` at a specific row by adding that row and another row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [0,1,2,3],
    'B': [0,1,2,3],
    'C': [10,10,10,10]
})

mask1 = df['A']==1
mask2 = df['B']==2
df.loc[mask1, 'C'] = df.loc[mask1, 'C'] + df.loc[mask2, 'C']
```

In the last line, because we are adding two `pd.Series` together, it tries to match the index and therefore would return NaN instead of the expected 10 + 10=20.

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use select first value from `Series` by `df.loc[mask2, 'C']`

```
df.loc[mask1, 'C'] = df.loc[mask1, 'C'] + df.loc[mask2, 'C'].iat[0]

df.loc[mask1, 'C'] = df.loc[mask1, 'C'] + df.loc[mask2, 'C'].to_numpy()[0]
```

If possible `mask2` return all `False`s use:

```
df.loc[mask1, 'C'] = df.loc[mask1, 'C'] + next(iter(df.loc[mask2, 'C']), 0)
print (df)
   A  B   C
0  0  0  10
1  1  1  20
2  2  2  10
3  3  3  10
```

Comment: I went with the `to_numpy` solution.